# Logic to convert flat JSON to nested JSON

Tags: python, json, algorithm

I have a flat JSON where keys represent different levels.

For example:

```
data = {
      "name": "John",
      "age": 30,
      "address:city": "New-York",
      "address:street": "5th avenue",
      "address:number": 10,
}
```

As you can see keys contains `:` which is the separator for the level.

I would like to convert it to have something like this:

```
wanted = {
      "name": "John",
      "age": 30,
      "address": {
            "city": "New-York",
            "street": "5th avenue",
            "number": 10
      }
}
```

I'm working with Python but here I'm more looking just for logic advice, what would be the best approach to solve this problem in a generic way (not for this specific example only)

Thanks for your help

Comment: [Unflatten with custom separator](https://github.com/amirziai/flatten).

Comment: I'd tackle this situation by converting to a dict (if not done), then I would loop the keys and either `split()` or check if the key has a `:`, if so I'd then build a "final" dict and start populating the fields you need. All you are going to need to do is loop your keys and build a new dict the way you wish...simple logic of iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive approach that supports multiple levels of nesting.

```py
from typing import Any

def build(key: list[str], value: Any, res: dict):
    k, *r = key
    if r:
        if not res.get(k):
            res[k] = {}
        build(r, value, res[k])
    else:
        res[k] = value

res = {}
for k, v in data.items():
    build(k.split(":"), v, res)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a nice way to handle this!

Answer (score 1):

I think an easy approach would be to create a method that maps this JSON to an object, and then convert the object to another object with attributes such as in the "wanted" one, and then you can simply convert the result object to JSON that will have "wanted" structure

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```bash
jq 'reduce to_entries[] as {$key, $value} ({}; setpath($key / ":"; $value))'
```

**Output**

```json
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "address": {
    "city": "New-York",
    "street": "5th avenue",
    "number": 10
  }
}
```

---

If you want the keys sorted:

```bash
jq '. as $obj
    | reduce keys[] as $key ({}; . * setpath($key | split(":"); $obj[$key]))'
```

**Output**

```json
{
  "address": {
    "city": "New-York",
    "number": 10,
    "street": "5th avenue"
  },
  "age": 30,
  "name": "John"
}
```

---

The code works for more than one nested level (e.g. additional entry `"contact:phone:work": "110"`)

Comment: Thanks but this was only an example. I'm looking for an algorithm that can convert any JSON

Comment: Ahh, I understand. Would `jq` be ok for you if it solves the problem in general?

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

```
def convert(inp, sep=':'):
    output = {}
    for key, value in inp.items():
        *path, skey = key.split(sep)
        dest = output
        for p in path:
            if p not in dest:
                dest[p] = dict()
            dest = dest[p]
        dest[skey] = value
    return output
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Data input
data = {
      "name": "John",
      "age": 30,
      "address:city": "New-York",
      "address:street": "5th avenue",
      "address:number": 10,
}

# Initiate output
output = {

}

# Get keys in data
keys = data.keys()

# Iterate through keys
for i in keys:
    
    # If there is a seperator, make sub-dcitionary. If not then proceed to add data normally.
    if ":" in i:

        # Extract subdictionary title and element name
        split = i.split(":")

        # If the subdictionary doesn't already exist, create it
        if not (split[0] in output.keys()):
            output[split[0]] = {}

        # Add element to subdictionary
        output[split[0]][split[1]]=data[i]
    else:
        output[i]=data[i]

# Print out results
print(output)
```

Results

```
{'name': 'John', 'age': 30, 'address': {'city': 'New-York', 'street': '5th avenue', 'number': 10}}
```